# Android TranslateAnimation not playing on click

Tags: android, animation, onclick, translate-animation

I have the following animation I want to be played:

```
    public void onConfirmPayment(View view){        
         Animation flowAway = new TranslateAnimation(0, 400, 0, 0);
         flowAway.setDuration(1500);
         dummyTextView.setAnimation(flowAway);
         flowAway.start();
    }
```

The Method is invoked when a ImageButton is clicked on. The problem is: The animation doesn't play, unless when i turn the device (orientation change) than it plays the animation which it should have played when i clicked the button. I never experienced something like this, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it's clear now: I was such an idiot. It simply wouldn't execute the animation since there was no program instruction after the start() call of the animation.

Since I wanted the TextView to disappear after the animation, I simply added `dummyTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` and it works like it should.

Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: BTW, you probably don't want to use fixed numbers in the animation params, use DP sizes instead (you can convert them to pixels using the display metrics)

Comment: Why would Android need an instruction after the .start() to start the animation....